# How to call a ASP.NET CORE WEB API 3.1 from HTML Submit button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I have a very basic question , How to send the text box values on Submit Click to Action method  in ASP .Net Core Web API 3.1,

```
<form method="post" >
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstName"><br><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname"><br><br>
        <label for="email">Email ID:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I have created my Employee Model

```
public string firstName { get; set; }
public string lastname { get; set; }
public string emailid { get; set; }
```

I have my Action Method too

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult InsertEmployeeData ([FromBody] Employee employee)
    {
        var emplFirstName = employee.firstName;
        var empLastName = employee.lastname;
        return Ok();
    }
```

The available samples in internet are mostly with VIEW as example, but i have a plain html file "Home.html" my wwwroot directory of project, Which need to send value to action method on a click of submit button, is there any way of achieving it without using AJAX Call, View.

Do Share your Ideas/Knowledge

Thank you

Comment: Do you know how the url looks like? if yes then it is a basic ajax call to the given url with a deconstructed employee in the body. That's how it worked with my last asp.net core project (but that's from half a year ago).

Comment: @Brezelmann So , is it a must to use AJAX Calls and no other ways?

Comment: No you cann submit the information using any other normal way as long as you know the correct url to the endpoint you want to hit. You mentioned ajax and that was the easiest to answer.

Comment: can you share  code reference for any other way?

Comment: no not directly because i always could use ajax. I remembered however reading on a microsoft page that there are other options than ajax. Unfortenately I am unable to find said article that gave to overview with all available options. The only one I found was: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @SupriyaChandrasekaran Any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: @BrandoZhang yeah, it helped , but i went with a different approach

Answer (score 1):

Set name to form

```
<form method="post" name="FormEmployee" >
   <label for="fname">First name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstName"><br><br>
   <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname"><br><br>
   <label for="email">Email ID:</label>
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and add script

```
document.forms["FormEmployee"].addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = document.forms["FormEmployee"];
    const response = await fetch("api/{controller name}", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            firstName: form.elements["firstName"].value,
            lastname: form.elements["lastname"].value,
            email: form.elements["email"].value
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the fomrbody will not accept Form-data, it will accept json format or else.

If you want to post the data from html to webapi, you should use `[FromForm]` instead and make sure the html page and the web api is inside the same project.

Then you should add the right controller/action path in the action attribute in the form tag.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
<form method="post" action="WeatherForecast/InsertEmployeeData">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstName"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname"><br><br>
    <label for="email">Email ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Api:

```
    [HttpPost("InsertEmployeeData")]
    public IActionResult InsertEmployeeData([FromForm] Employee employee)
    {
        var emplFirstName = employee.firstName;
        var empLastName = employee.lastname;
        return Ok();
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works. No script needed. Small bug: In the form change the name propery of the emailtext input to emailId.